# Delete a file, if it is empty except for a header row

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to delete a file if its empty, apart from the header.

Comment: You should [start with learning the very basics of Powershell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276). It is far beyond the scope of SO to teach you how to write basic Powershell scripts. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[postanote's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796568/45375) provides some useful background information on the use of the `Measure-Object` cmdlet.

In the case at hand, however, it's simpler and faster to use the following:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\FileOfInterest'

if ((Get-Content -First 2 $file).Count -le 1) {
  Remove-Item $file
}
```

- `Get-Content -First 2 $file` returns up to 2 lines from the start of file `$file`, as an *array*.

  - Note:`-First` is a more descriptive alias for the `-TotalCount` parameter; in PowerShell v2, use the latter.
- `(...).Count` counts the elements of that array, i.e., the number of lines actually read.<sup>[1]</sup>
- `-le 1` (`-le` meaning *less-than-or-equal*) returns `$true` if, despite asking for *2* lines, only 0 or 1 are returned.
- The `Remove-Item` call then removes file `$file`.

---

<sup>[1] Up to PowerShell version 2, `.Count` would return `$null` if only *1* line had been read, because PowerShell returns a *single* output object as-is instead of wrapping it in a single-element array. However, since `$null` is coerced to `0` in a numerical comparison such as with `-le`, ths solution works in v2 as well. PowerShell versions 3 and higher implicitly implement a `.Count` property even on *scalars* (single objects), which - sensibly - returns `1`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the below which works $infa_shre_tgt=$env:INFA_SHARED_HOME+"\TgtFiles\UCPath\"
if(
(Get-content $infa_shre_tgt\ods_cdm_rec_count_mismatch.txt | Measure-Object -Line).count -eq 1)
{Remove-Item $infa_shre_tgt\ods_cdm_rec_count_mismatch.txt}
exit

Comment: @kabdul: Thanks for accepting the answer, but the code in your comment (please generally don't post multi-line code in comments, as it is hard to read) doesn't work: use `.Lines` instead of `.Count` to make it work. As stated, however, the solution in my answer - which doesn't require `Measure-Object` - is both more concise and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed Olaf...

Khader - What did you search for. There are samples of how to count lines in a file all over the web.

Just search for 'powershell count lines in file'

Example hits.

[Use a PowerShell Cmdlet to Count Files, Words, and Lines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-count-files-words-and-lines/)

[How to count number of lines and words in a file using Powershell?](http://karunsubramanian.com/windows/how-to-count-number-of-lines-and-words-in-a-file-using-powershell/)

> If I want to know how many lines are contained in the file, I use the
>   Measure-Object cmdlet with the line switch. This command is shown
>   here:

```
Get-Content C:\fso\a.txt | Measure-Object –Line
```

> If I need to know the number of characters, I use the character
>   switch:

```
Get-Content C:\fso\a.txt | Measure-Object -Character
```

> There is also a words switched parameter that will return the number
>   of words in the text file. It is used similarly to the character or
>   line switched parameter. The command is shown here:

```
Get-Content C:\fso\a.txt | Measure-Object –Word
```

> In the following figure, I use the Measure-Object cmdlet to count
>   lines; then lines and characters; and finally lines, characters, and
>   words. These commands illustrate combining the switches to return
>   specific information.

***Update for OP.***

You should have updated your original question for context vs putting your code in the comment

As for …

> Is there any way I can return just the count and use it with an if
>   statement to check if it is equal to 1, and then del the file

Just use the if statement when checking for the 'lines' count greater than 1

```
    If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Measure-Object –Line | Where-Object -Property Lines -gt 1)
    {
        'Count is greater than one'
        Remove-Item ...
    }
```

Again, this is very basic PowerShell overview stuff, so it's prudent you take Olaf's suggestion to limit future confusion, frustrations, misconceptions and errors you are going to encounter.

Comment: Hi,  I am trying to check the number of lines in the file. If it is equal to 1, I want to delete the file. I am using Get-content ods_cdm_rec_count_mismatch.txt | Measure-Object and it returns    Count    : 1
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :   Is there any way I can return just the count and use it with an if statement to check if it is equal to 1, and then del the file